# What is the meaning of "The package is inside a non-bundle dependency" warning in a Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I encountered the warning when I imported my Maven project in IntelliJ:

```
The package 'org.xml.sax' is inside a non-bundle dependency
```

There are, in fact, 3 packages causing this: `org.xml.sax`, `javax.servlet`, and `javax.xml.parsers`. I have checked `pom.xml` and these packages weren't there except for `javax.servlet`.

Do I need to add the missing packages to the `pom.xml`? The program works but it would be better to get rid of this warning. I would also like to know if there are any expected problems when this warning is present.

This is the project's `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>com.project.name</groupId>
      <artifactId>project-name</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
   </parent>
   <packaging>bundle</packaging>
   <name>Project Name</name>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <source>${java.version}</source>
               <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
               <instructions>
                  <Embed-Dependency>jackson-core, jackson-annotations, jackson-databind, handlebars, antlr4-runtime, rhino, jsoup, commons-csv, jose4j</Embed-Dependency>
                  <Export-Package>com.project.name.core.*, com.fasterxml.jackson.core.*, com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*,</Export-Package>
                  <Sling-Model-Packages>com.project.name.core</Sling-Model-Packages>
               </instructions>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
               <check>
                  <branchRate>85</branchRate>
                  <lineRate>85</lineRate>
                  <haltOnFailure>false</haltOnFailure>
                  <totalBranchRate>85</totalBranchRate>
                  <totalLineRate>85</totalLineRate>
                  <packageLineRate>85</packageLineRate>
                  <packageBranchRate>85</packageBranchRate>
               </check>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>clean</goal>
                     <goal>check</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
   <profiles>
      <profile>...</profile>
   </profiles>
   <dependencies>
      <!-- the core, which includes Streaming API, shared low-level abstractions 
                        (but NOT data-binding) -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Just the annotations; use this dependency if you want to attach 
                        annotations to classes without connecting them to the code. -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <!-- databinding; ObjectMapper, JsonNode and related classes are here -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <!-- CSV Parser -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
         <version>1.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- OSGi Dependencies -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
         <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
         <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>biz.aQute</groupId>
         <artifactId>bndlib</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
         <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
         <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Other Dependencies -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.jcr</groupId>
         <artifactId>jcr</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
         <artifactId>aem-api</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.project.name</groupId>
         <artifactId>core</artifactId>
         <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
         <artifactId>org.apache.sling.models.api</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Testing -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
         <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>junit-addons</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit-addons</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
         <version>2.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
         <artifactId>org.apache.sling.i18n</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.github.jknack</groupId>
         <artifactId>handlebars</artifactId>
         <version>4.0.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.mozilla</groupId>
         <artifactId>rhino</artifactId>
         <version>1.7R4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
         <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
         <version>4.5.1-1</version>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.abego.treelayout</groupId>
               <artifactId>org.abego.treelayout.core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
         <artifactId>org.apache.sling.commons.json</artifactId>
         <version>2.0.10</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
         <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
         <version>1.8.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
         <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
         <version>1.9.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.bitbucket.b_c</groupId>
         <artifactId>jose4j</artifactId>
         <version>0.5.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
         <version>3.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
         <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
         <version>1.4</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Please [see the answer in IntelliJ IDEA forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207768185-What-does-The-package-javax-xml-bind-is-inside-a-non-bundle-dependency-warning-mean-). Your project seems to use OSGi, hence the inspection is active.

Comment: I'd rather not modify the active inspections. Is there any change I can make to `pom.xml` to make this disappear?

Comment: Show your `pom.xml` and someone may suggest the change.